# Python subprocess doesn't reload Nginx

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx

In a python script (3.7), I am trying simply to reload Nginx after a configuration have been created :

```
    import sys
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    import subprocess
    import psycopg2
    import dns.resolver
    import logging
    import os
    [...]
      logging.info(hostname+':Preparing configuration file')
      conf = content.replace('%%hostname%%', hostname)
      logging.info(hostname+':Creating configuration file')
      f = open(hostname + '.conf', 'w+')
      f.write(conf)
      f.close
      subprocess.run(["sudo", "mv", "/home/app/domain_script/"+hostname+".conf", "/etc/nginx/sites-available/"])
      subprocess.run(["sudo", "ln", "-s", "/etc/nginx/sites-available/"+hostname+".conf", "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/"])
      subprocess.run(["sudo", "service", "nginx", "reload"])
    [...]
```

But I noticed that Nginx is not reloaded. The configuration is not active and no error is showed.

I tried with :

```
subprocess.run(["sudo", "/usr/sbin/service", "nginx", "reload"])
subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "/usr/sbin/service", "nginx", "reload"])
subprocess.call(["sudo", "/usr/sbin/service", "nginx", "reload"])
```

Also with adding below : `time.sleep(10)`

All without success.

If a stop the script and then manullay type in shell : `service nginx reload` - its working

It works if the command is the last code to be executed or in an python file with this command only.

User is in sudoer list and does not required a password.

Comment: Check the output from the command. Pass `capture_output=True` to the `run()` call, get the return value & check the contents of stdout & stdin

Comment: Its empty :

    `capture = subprocess.run(["sudo", "/usr/sbin/service", "nginx", "reload"], capture_output=True)
    print (capture.stderr)
    print (capture.stdout)
    print (capture.stdin)`

Comment: When manually running ``service nginx reload``, do you do so with or without ``sudo``?

Comment: Always with sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours, it finnaly works with :

```
subprocess.run(["systemctl", "reload", "nginx"])
```

Answer (score -1):

"Subprocess" is one of the most important and most well documented module with an immense amount of customization around it. This makes it one of the most challenging one as well.

To get  to your question, [here](https://github.com/vaddisrinivas/small_script) is a small utility that helped me sometime ago in automating something similar

```py
import subprocess
import sys
def shell_output(param):
    """
        This method just takes the shell commands to be executed and returns what
        this command outputs in shell
        :param param: command (example "ls")
        :return: string of commands output on shell
        """
    try:
        x = ((subprocess.Popen(
                    [str(param)],#takes each part of command as a list element,
                    shell=True,#to run in shell
                    bufsize=0, 
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, #to give it to pipe
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, #to give errors also to pipe
                    universal_newlines=False,#shall it include the newline 
                )).communicate()[0]#this is to get the value from shell
            .decode("utf-8")#this is to remove 'b i.e to convert from byte to string
        ).strip()
        return x .
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error with execution in get_str " + str(e))
        return e

print("The text files available are : \n"+shell_output("ls *txt"))
```

Solution :

```py
your_command="service nginx reload"
#this will execute the command and also validate its execution using "$?"
print(shell_output("{}; echo $?;".format(your_command)))
```

Please try it and let me know if it helps :)

Comment: There are ``subprocess.run`` and various other convenience functions these days. No need to reinvent the wheel badly.

Comment: subprocess.run does continue to serve, but, there are a certain number of improvements required. reference -> https://bugs.python.org/issue37424 , but, subprocess.Popen() is yet another utility that helps

Comment: Thanks but i have the same result. It seems that it wont if chained severals subprocess.run. I am still investigating